# Different Distributions?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If there is a PDF $\text{f}(x)$, and $x$ follows different distributions, for example, Rayleigh, Rice, Nakagami, and Weibull. Then what will be the distribution of $|x|^2$ for these distributions? Please refer me to any book, research paper or any article which helps me with this.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Probability/Transformation_of_Probability_Densities#Function_of_a_Random_Variable_(n=1,_m=1)

Answer (score 1):

If $Y$ is a random variable whose support is $[0, \infty)$, i.e. perhaps one of the 4 distributions you specified, and you want to compute $X = \sqrt{Y}$, then the CDF of $X$ will be given by:
\begin{align}
  F_X(x) &= \Pr(X\le x) \\
  &= \Pr(\sqrt{Y}\le x) \\
  &= \Pr(Y\le x^2) \\
  &= F_Y(x^2)
\end{align}
So you just have to substitute $x^2$ into the CDF of each of those 4 distributions. If you want to get the PDF you can differentiate with respect to $x$.

For example, for the [Rayleigh distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution) the CDF is
$$
  F_Y(y) = 1 - \exp\left( \frac{-y^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)
$$

So the CDF of $X = \sqrt{Y}$ is therefore
$$
  F_X(x) = F_Y(x^2) = 1 - \exp\left( \frac{-x^4}{2\sigma^2} \right)
$$

If you want to get the PDF you can differentiate.
$$
  f_X(x) = \frac{d}{dx}F_X(x) = \frac{2x^3}{\sigma^2}\exp\left( \frac{-x^4}{2\sigma^2} \right)
$$

Finally, note that $\mathbf{E}[\sqrt{Y}]\neq\sqrt{\mathbf{E}[Y]}$ - you can't get the expected value of the new random variable by taking the square root of the old one! In fact, Jensen's inequality & the fact that $\sqrt{\;\;}$ is strictly concave guarantee that $\mathbf{E}[\sqrt{Y}] < \sqrt{\mathbf{E}[Y]}$. The expectation of the new RV will be
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{E}[\sqrt{Y}] &= \frac{1}{4} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \sqrt{\sigma\sqrt{2}} \\
  &\neq \sqrt{\sigma\sqrt{\pi/2}} = \sqrt{\mathbf{E}[Y]}
\end{align}

Here's [a Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gzofmx4iud) that lets you mess around with the Rayleigh distribution & the square root of the same.

For some of the other distributions you mentioned, it will be straightforward enough to plug $x^2$ into the CDF instead of $x$, but it may be difficult to differentiate and get the PDF of the resulting distribution.